# Primeng 14.1.2 doesn't show toggle button even after import, no errors on console

Tags: primeng, angular14

My module declaration is like this

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {InplaceModule} from 'primeng/inplace';
import { ResultadoImoveisResidenciaisVendaRoutingModule } from './resultado-imoveis-residenciais-venda-routing.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CoreModule } from 'src/app/core/core.module';
import { DropdownModule } from 'primeng/dropdown';
import {ToggleButtonModule} from 'primeng/togglebutton';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ResultadoImoveisResidenciaisVendaRoutingModule,
    InplaceModule,
    FormsModule,
    CoreModule,
    DropdownModule,
    ToggleButtonModule
  ]

})
export class ResultadoImoveisResidenciaisVendaModule { }
```

My template is like this

```
             <p-toggleButton [(ngModel)]="val"></p-toggleButton>
```

Nothings appears. If someone can help.

Comment: Good selectbutton also does't not. I placed a tabview and it worked so it is something very strange related to selectbutton and togglebutton.

Comment: I've tried to update to the latest version of primeng 14 and same result. sad!

Comment: p-paginator enters the party. Also doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

I am bulding a portfolio, I chose PrimeNg because I learned about it on my last job. I thought it very suitable for to style a website to show off to someone else. It's so frustrating that sometimes third party libraries let you down, I would have to use bootstrap or a custom pager that would break my layout design, as I was counting on putting it afterwards after styling other aspects of the page. Fortunatelly I found the solution

```
**We have to import it on the app module and on the feature module that you are working on, both places!.
```

I am "playing" with this project for

years and I forgot about it because I had some time since I last worked with it